# @WebAppConfiguration pre Spring 3.2.x

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-mvc-test

I'm writing a bunch of spring-mvc tests, but I'm using Spring 3.1, there are some issues right now with upgrading to post 3.1 so I'm not attempting that at this time.

My question is, I have a spring controller test but I'm trying to inject a WebApplicationContext into the test, and everywhere I've looked this is done through @WebAppConfiguration annotation.  This annotation doesn't exist in Spring 3.1, how was this done pre 3.2?

Thanks!
Alessandro Ferrucci

Comment: If I am not mistaken, there was a separate Spring MVC test project that you could use

Comment: Yeah this is it https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-test-mvc however I don't know what the equivalent to the @WebApplicationContext was in that project (there is no such annotation in that project).